# Angular2 ng-template

Tags: html, angular

I am using the version 2.4.9 of Angular.
I would like to declare an html element that I can use in several places :

```
<div #template>
 foo
</div>
<header>
 {{ template }}
</header>
<body>
 {{ template }}
</body>
```

It obviously doesn't work, and the solution would be to create a component. I have seen in angular4 that something calls `ng-template` does exist. Is there anything similar in angular 2.4.X ?

Comment: Where did you find the 4.0.0 docs ? I am searching for them

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is `ngTemplateOutlet` directive that can help you:

```
<template #myTemplate>
   foo
</template>
<header>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></ng-container>
</header>
<div>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: can we add a url for that template ? and then use the link in ng-container?

Comment: @Apoorv  What do you mean? Parameter?

Comment: i mean that 
<template #myTemplate>
   foo
</template> can be put in a seperate file and then in 
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="URL here"></ng-container> ?

Comment: @Apoorv `myTemplate` should be instance of `TemplateRef` you can pass it where do you want from. Nope, you can't do that